# Shift js string one character

Tags: javascript, hash

In PHP, it's pretty simple, I'd assume, `array_shift($string)`?

If not, I'm sure there's some equally simple solution :)

However, is there any way to achieve the same thing in JavaScript?

My specific example is the pulling of `window.location.hash` from the address bar in order to dynamically load a specific AJAX page. If the hash was "2", i.e. http://foo.bar.com#2...

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // hash would be "#2"
```

I'd ideally like to take the `#` off, so a simple `2` gets fed into the function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
hash = hash.substr(1);
```

This will take off the first character of `hash` and return everything else. This is actually similar in functionality to the PHP [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function, which is probably what you should be using to get substrings of strings in PHP rather than `array_shift` anyway (I didn't even know `array_shift` would work with strings!)

Comment: Cheers to the both of you :)

As far as I know, "string" isn't exactly a real type, but rather an array of characters, as we've all been taught way way (way?) back when.

Theoretically, it should work, as you can point to a character in a string with $string[x].

Comment: I just tried it out, and `array_shift` actually *does not* work on strings in PHP, which makes sense to me. @Julian: what you say is true of strings in C and C++ but in most other languages (Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc), strings are their own data type mostly unrelated to arrays.

Comment: Use `substring` instead of `substr`. The former is standardised.

Answer (score 5):

As you suspected, there's also a `shift()` function on the `Array` prototype ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)).

Strings are not `Array`s, they are ["array-like objects"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) so to call `shift()` on a `String`, it must be `split()` first:

```
var arr = str.split("");
var char = arr.shift();
var originalString = arr.join("");
```

Comment: Using the original example, you'd always get the `#` (the first character, the one that got shifted) with this approach, which doesn't seem to be the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ben's point regarding conversion to an Array, given that we are assuming there is only one character as the hash, and that it is the last character, we should really just use:

```
var hash = window.location.split("").pop();
```